TYPO3 Powermail: Skip to a certain form page
I'm working on a TYPO3 website that has a Powermail form with multiple pages. One of the pages would have a pair of radio buttons, where it is mandatory to select one of them to progress. One should display the usual link leading to the next page, while the other should make a link appear, which skips the next four pages.
Is there a function inside Powermail, which enables one to skip form pages? I looked in the documentation of Powermail and on other websites, and I couldn't find anything about such a function. If not, are there any approaches I could take to make this possible? Just a nudge in the right direction would be helpful.

Is this a JS issue or a PHP issue? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

I took both the JS and PHP tags out, after I realised it's not really an issue with either of the two.
Regarding my attempts to solve it, I didn't get far, since I didn't even know where to begin, having found barely any resources that could have helped me.

You could hide fields based on a given value if you use the extension powermail_cond.
Depending on your initial selection you could hide fields on the next four pages.
